# Typescript inlined in Django html

Tags: django, typescript

I'm trying to combine Typescript and Django. What I've manage to do was to use Django Compressor which gives me possibility to import compiled typescript file. But what if I needed to inline typescript code in html?

E.g:

```
<script> require('path/to/my/file.ts') </script>
```

I found that repo https://github.com/MasterKale/django-brunch-ts-scss and it shows that it is possible but I can't figure it out how can I accomplished that without using Brunch.io

Comment: Could you find a solution to this?

Comment: Not really, I was able to drop inline ts in html files for now. But any ideas how to accomplish that would be apprichated.